# Compile performance when deploying a rails app on multiple workers on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2

I am running a legacy PHP app behind nginx on multiple medium worker instances on EC2 (ubuntu 12.04).

I want to deploy a rails app on these instances now and am worried about the compile time for ruby, rails and other gems that the app depends on:

rbenv install 1.9.3-p545 took "7m48.611s". This is an instance where nothing else is running on at the moment. Rails is still compiling on this instance (~20mins). I just started using --no-ri and --no-rdoc which seems to help a bit.

There are several options now that I can think of to make this go faster:
1) using the OS package manager to install ruby and rails, but that would limit me to the specific versions in the apt-get repository.

2) compile on one instance and rsync or scp the binaries to the other workers, probably comes with debt when maintaining this solution.

3) just compile ruby, rails and the other gems and accept that the workers will have 100% load when the compile is running, this will greatly increase the time it takes to spin up a new instance though, from currently ~3 minutes to 30 minutes or longer.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is it practical for you to compile once, then construct an AWS image you can relaunch?

Comment: Which medium instance are you using? Although with ec2, speed is going to come by taking advantage of threading.

Comment: Creating the image is not too bad of an idea, although that would mean to migrate the existing workers over to the new images and adding them to the existing load balancer while taking the old images out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can answer this myself now:

Most of the time compiling was spent compiling the documentation.
Using --no-ri and --no-rdoc reduced the compile time to ~5 minutes per worker.

I ended up compiling not on all of the workers at the same time, but on one worker at a time and therefore not interrupting service.

Thanks for the replies!